# Почему второй виджет вставленный в QStackedWidget создаётся только на последнем цикле?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qstackedwidget

Возникла проблема: при добавлении `QStackedWidget` в `QTableWidget` циклом, второй виджет, вставленный в `QStackedWidget` добавляется только на последнем цикле. Хотя первый виджет добавляется в каждом цикле.
В чем может быть проблема?

Пример моего кода:

**Example.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centrawidget)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centrawidget)

        self.table = QTableWidget(5, 1)
        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            column3_frame1 = QFrame()
            column3_g_box1 = QGridLayout()
            column3_frame1.setLayout(column3_g_box1)
            column3_g_box1.addWidget(QLabel("Hello"), 0, 1, 1, 1)

            column3_frame2 = QFrame()
            column3_g_box2 = QGridLayout()
            column3_frame2.setLayout(column3_g_box2)
            column3_g_box2.addWidget(QLabel("Bye"), 0, 1, 1, 1)

            self.column3_stacked_w = QStackedWidget()
            self.column3_stacked_w.addWidget(column3_frame1)
            self.column3_stacked_w.addWidget(column3_frame2)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, self.column3_stacked_w)

        self.hello_btn = QPushButton("Hello")
        self.hello_btn.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.column3_stacked_w.setCurrentIndex(0))

        self.bye_btn = QPushButton("Bye")
        self.bye_btn.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.column3_stacked_w.setCurrentIndex(1))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hello_btn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.bye_btn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centrawidget)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centrawidget)
        
        self.table = QTableWidget(5, 1)
# +++
        self.table_row_column = {}                                               # +++
        
        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            column3_frame1 = QFrame()
            column3_g_box1 = QGridLayout(column3_frame1)
#               vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  просто мне так удобнее читать           
#               column3_frame1.setLayout(column3_g_box1)
            column3_g_box1.addWidget(QLabel(f"Hello {row}"), 0, 1)

            column3_frame2 = QFrame()
            column3_g_box2 = QGridLayout(column3_frame2)
            column3_g_box2.addWidget(QLabel(f"Bye {row}"), 0, 1)

#            self.column3_stacked_w = QStackedWidget()
#            ^^^^ убираем, см. print ниже
            column3_stacked_w = QStackedWidget()
            column3_stacked_w.addWidget(column3_frame1)
            column3_stacked_w.addWidget(column3_frame2)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, column3_stacked_w)

# +++            
            print(f'{column3_stacked_w}') #
            self.table_row_column[row, 0] = column3_stacked_w                    # +++

        self.hello_btn = QPushButton("Hello")
        self.hello_btn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.column0_stacked_w("Hello")) # +++
#            lambda: self.column3_stacked_w.setCurrentIndex(0))

        self.bye_btn = QPushButton("Bye")
        self.bye_btn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.column0_stacked_w("Bye"))     # +++

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hello_btn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.bye_btn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def column0_stacked_w(self, text):
        if text == "Hello":
            for v in self.table_row_column.values():
                v.setCurrentIndex(0)
        elif text == "Bye":
            for v in self.table_row_column.values():
                v.setCurrentIndex(1)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Совсем не понимаю, почему это работает, а мой код нет. Странно что в PyQt такие недоработки. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Rett_oo потому что в каждой ячейке свой объект `column3_stacked_w` и эти объекты надо прокрутить чтобы в каждом поменять `setCurrentIndex`

Comment: Понял, спасибо за объяснение.